# How can I associate the preview display range with the ImageCapture range on Android CameraX?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, androidx

In Android CameraX,
I want to make a rectangle in the Preview and export the range as a Bitmap.

However,I don't know how to associate the range displayed in Preview with the range in ImageCapture.
Because of that, I can't do it.

I want to know either (1) or (2)

(1) How to export the image displayed in Preview with Bitmap.

(2) How to know what percentage of the width of ImageCapture the width of Preview is displayed.

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying the screen size of Preview in TargetResolution of Preview and ImageCapture,
I solved the problem.

```
private fun startCamera() {
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
        val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
        val provider = binding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider

        // Preview
        val preview = Preview.Builder()
            .setTargetResolution(Size(binding.viewFinder.width, binding.viewFinder.height))
            .setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_0)
        .build()
            .also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(provider)
            }

        imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
            .setTargetResolution(Size(binding.viewFinder.width, binding.viewFinder.height))
            .setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_0)
            .build()

        // Select back camera as a default
        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

        val aspectRatio = Rational(binding.viewFinder.width, binding.viewFinder.height)
        val viewPort = ViewPort.Builder(aspectRatio, preview.getTargetRotation()).build()

        val useCaseGroup = UseCaseGroup.Builder()
            .addUseCase(preview)
            .addUseCase(imageCapture!!)
            .setViewPort(viewPort)
             .build()

        try {
            // Unbind use cases before rebinding
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()

            // Bind use cases to camera
            cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this, cameraSelector, useCaseGroup)

        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
        }

    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
}
```